# Can i operate InfluxDB with no use memory?

Tags: influxdb

Due to InfluxDB will take my RAM depleted over time. Becasue of the reading speed in my case is not important, now i dont want to store data in memory, just on disk

Can i do that? If yes then how?

Comment: InfluxDB usually requires more RAM than other time series databases when working with high number of time series (aka high cardinality). For instance, it [requires up to 10x more RAM than VictoriaMetrics](https://medium.com/@valyala/insert-benchmarks-with-inch-influxdb-vs-victoriametrics-e31a41ae2893) on high cardinality data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to operate InfluxDB without using memory. Data in InfluxDB is not held in memory indefinitely and will be persisted to disk. A health InfluxDB instance will appear to consume all of the memory on a machine, but the OS will be able to free that memory if need be.

Comment: so what is the best option to run Influx with high performance and minimum of memory usage? I chosen reducing retention policy on database, is that right?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by high performance and minimum memory?